# Faster grepping through lots of bulky text files

Tags: search, grep

I have log files that are 500 mb each and there are 200 of such files.

I need to grep certain patterns inside these files. But this takes up a lot of time!

Is there a (open source) software that can index these log files (whatever time it takes in this initial step), and later it can do super quick greps of all the patterns I want?

Comment: OS might help... there is grep for Windows, you know.

Comment: I am using cygwin's grep. Are you saying "grep for windows" is any faster? and does it do indexing?

Comment: I'm just thinking there may be alternative search methods/tools that are OS specific. I'm not too familiar with any, but that could help other answerers. When I said grep for Windows, I was referring to various ports of grep (such as Cygwin's), not a specific program. By your question, your OS is rather ambibious. In fact, when you said grep, I assumed Linux at first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need a desktop search engine.

For Linux look [here](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/best-linux-desktop-search-tools). I have used Recoll, it was generally good. But it sometimes didn't recognise text files correctly.

For Windows I recommend [X1](http://www.x1.com), it is excellent and comes with a free trial period.